# Forcing trailing slash before query params with OkHttp3

Tags: android, url, okhttp, trailing-slash

I have a `String` url with queries (`https://example.com/path/segments?q1=1&q2=2` for example). I need to add trailing slash (`https://example.com/path/segments`**/**`?q1=1&q2=2`) before queries if it does not exist using okhttp 3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`httpUrlBuilder.addPathSegment("")`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-http-url/-builder/add-path-segment/) to force a trailing slash at the end of the path. HttpUrl models each path segment as being prefixed by a `/`, with an empty string indicating a lone slash.

Answer (score 3):

Before using the string you could just do an replace on the `?` and replace it with `/?` and you get the result you want.

Here's an example in Kotlin

```
var url:String = "https://example.com/path/segments?q1=1&q2=2"
url = url.replace("?", "/?")
```

This should work since the query variables should be urlencoded and there should only be one occurence of `?` in your urls.

Comment: It will work, but I thought there is something better with [HttpUrl.Builder](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-http-url/-builder/) using